# Software doesn't allow indentation fix

Tags: discussion, bug

I found a question on stackoverflow with an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085063/rails-simple-form-country-select/31220841#31220841) that helped me. So I upvoted it and while at it I thought I could fix that bad indentation of this post. (See screenshot 1)

[image: screenshot 1]

Unfortunately the software doesn't let me edit it. (See screenshot 2)

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

I have deleted 15 unnecessairy spaces, which are 15 characters to me, but not to the software.

Is this a bug, or is this behaviour intended?

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: I think this behavior is intended. Apparently there's a reputation and/or editing badge requirement to make this kind of edit. I was able to make the same change with no obstruction.

Comment: It is not easy to indent code while posting an answer on question. :(